# Функции модератора в чате

Tags: php

Доброго временм суток всем. Я только начинаю изучать php и в качесте учебного материала писал гостевую книгу... ну что - то типа того... сейчас хочу немного усовершенствовать ее,(добавить смайлы, приватные сообщения, модераторские ф-ции) но столкнулся с проблемой реализации модераторских ф-ций... с удалением сообщений проблем нет... проблема с реализацией БАНА и ПИНКА из комнаты... как могу предположить, БАН можно сделать в таблице user. добавить строку ban и поставить там значение 0... когда давать бан пользователю, то в это поле вставлять дату например 2012-06-15 12:03:56. и прописать услоовие, что если текушее время меньше времени в поле ban, то при любом действии пользователя просто обновлять страницу... а когда текущее время будет равным времени в поле ban,  то вставить в поле ban сново 0, тем самым сново разрешить пользователю писать сообщения... бред наверное... подскажите?

Comment: много текста... но по сути совсем не бред, технически все примерно так и реализовывается!

Comment: Только не понятно что должна делать кнопка кик в гостевой книге.

Comment: Я вот когда практиковался на PHP, социальную сеть написал =)

Answer (score 1):

А зачем прописывать 0 в бан? По мне достаточно просто условия проверки на то что текущее время больше времени бана - то нет бана, меньше или равно - то бан. А так идея здравая.